# kmz file not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a KMZ file that looks like this :

```
example.kmz:
  ->example.png
  ->example.kml
```

example.kml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Schema name="test" id="test">
    <SimpleField name="ID1" type="int"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
<Folder>
      <name>Ground Overlays</name>
      <visibility>0</visibility>
      <description>Examples of ground overlays</description>
      <GroundOverlay>
        <name>example overlay</name>
        <visibility>0</visibility>
        <description>Overlay example png.</description>
        <Icon>
          <href>example.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <LatLonBox>
          <north>50.080654</north>
          <south>50.079959</south>
          <east>19.993121</east>
          <west>19.992118</west>
          <rotation>0.0</rotation>
        </LatLonBox>
      </GroundOverlay>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

And a JS code that goes like this:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapDiv'), {
            zoom: 11,
            minZoom: 1,
            streetViewControl: false
        });

//adding kmz layer from file
var kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('/kml/example.kmz');
kmzLayer.setMap(map);

var markers = [];
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
//adding markers

// Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

The problem is, that map is generated OK, markers are ok, but there is no error in console, while groundOverlay from KMZ file is not rendered on a map.

I can't find reason for that - what do I miss?
I created KMZ file manually - maybe I missed something? but then, why there is no error?

Thanks for help

**EDIT1**
I checked my KMZ file with elsevier-apps.sciverse.com/GoogleMaps/verification
online validator - everything works fine there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it turned out - you cannot use local KML/KMZ files. All files must be access publicly, and you ought to put working URL in 
`new google.maps.KmlLayer(VALID_URL);`

or...
you can use [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) to parse local KMZ/KML files.

So now, everything is working just fine:) My KMZ file was correct, my JS code was also correct (except of this one part I described above). I hope it'll help someone:)